# Android have to wait when reading another characteristics

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, characteristics

I have an app that successfully reads different bluetooth characteristics. It works, but only if I wait a certain time between reading a different characteristic. This time varies between 70 and 200 milliseconds and i find it very annoying. Doesn anyone else experience this problem? Or does anyone know of a way to fix this?

Comment: Plenty of people experience it.  The Android APIs are not nice and are buggy as well.  Try throwing multiple devices concurrently into the mix for a real mess.  Sorry I don't have any real answers...

Comment: thanks for the answer, my experience has been exactly as you described :p

Answer (score 1):

This is a prevalent issue, i used to a request queue and a GATT timeout in processing different requests, it solved the problem for a certain extent i should say. 
Have a look at this https://git.ti.com/sensortag-20-android 
Ti people has a demo implementation of a BluetoothLeService, which has request queuing, may work for you.

Comment: Thank you. I implemented something similar.